# How to play an audio file one after another in Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, audio, java-me

I managed to create an application in Blackberry that plays audio file, but it will only plays one file. I try to use a for loop to play a few audio files.

I managed to play it, but it did not play the whole sound of the audio files, it just play the first audio files and second for a few seconds, and stop playing after that. The files that played also play the sound overlap each other which should not be happening.

How to play the full sound of the audio files one after another in Blackberry without stopping?

Here is my code for the application that I created with the for loop:

```
    package mypackage;

import javax.microedition.media.Manager;
import javax.microedition.media.MediaException;
import javax.microedition.media.Player;
import java.lang.Class;
import javax.microedition.rms.RecordStore;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import net.rim.device.api.media.protocol.ByteArrayInputStreamDataSource;
import net.rim.device.api.system.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.extension.container.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import java.io.IOException;

public class PlayMedia extends UiApplication{
    /**
     * Entry point for application
     * @param args Command line arguments (not used)
     */ 
    public static void main(String[] args){

        PlayMedia theApp = new PlayMedia();
        theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
    }

    public PlayMedia()
    {

        pushScreen(new PlayMediaScreen());


    }
    /**
     * A class extending the MainScreen class, which provides default standard
     * behavior for BlackBerry GUI applications.
     */
    final class PlayMediaScreen extends MainScreen
    {
        /**
         * Creates a new PlayMediaScreen object
         */
        PlayMediaScreen()
        {
            String test1 = "Test(2seconds).mp3";
            String test2 = "Test(2seconds)2.mp3";
            String test3 = "Test(2seconds)3.mp3";
            String test4 = "Test(2seconds)4.mp3";
            String test5 = "blind_willie.mp3";
            String mp3 = null;

            for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                if(i == 0){
                    mp3 = test1;
                }
                else if(i == 1){
                    mp3 = test2;
                }
                else if(i == 2){
                    mp3 = test3;
                }
                else if(i == 3){
                    mp3 = test4;
                }
                else if(i == 4){
                    mp3 = test5;
                }
                play(mp3);
            }
        }

        private void play(String mp3){

        Player p = null;

        InputStream stream = (InputStream)this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + mp3);

            try {
                //p = Manager.createPlayer(source);
                p = Manager.createPlayer(stream, "audio/mpeg");
                p.realize();
                p.prefetch();

                //testing
                System.out.println("Creating Players!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
                System.out.println("The mp3 is " + mp3 + "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

                //testing
                System.out.println("IO Exeception!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!1 " + e);

                //testing 
                System.out.println(p);

            } catch (MediaException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            //testing
            System.out.println("Media Exeception!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!1" + e);

            //testing 
            System.out.println(p);
            }
            /*
             * Best practice is to invoke realize(), then prefetch(), then start().
             * Following this sequence reduces delays in starting media playback.
             *
             * Invoking start() as shown below will cause start() to invoke  prefetch(0),
             * which invokes realize() before media playback is started.
             */
            try {
                p.start();
            } catch (MediaException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

                //testing
                System.out.println("Media Exeception for starting!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!1" + e);

                //testing 
                System.out.println(p);
            }

            /*try {
                p.stop();
            } catch (MediaException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }*/
            //p.deallocate();
            //p.close();



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can anyone help me please!!!! I need to complete it by tomorrow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I get it, this is my code. :D

```
package mypackage;

import javax.microedition.media.Manager;
import javax.microedition.media.MediaException;
import javax.microedition.media.Player;
import javax.microedition.media.PlayerListener;

import java.lang.Class;
import javax.microedition.rms.RecordStore;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import net.rim.device.api.media.protocol.ByteArrayInputStreamDataSource;
import net.rim.device.api.system.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.extension.container.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import java.io.IOException;

public class PlayMedia extends UiApplication{
    /**
     * Entry point for application
     * @param args Command line arguments (not used)
     */ 
    public static void main(String[] args){

        PlayMedia theApp = new PlayMedia();
        theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
    }

    public PlayMedia()
    {

        pushScreen(new PlayMediaScreen());


    }
    /**
     * A class extending the MainScreen class, which provides default standard
     * behavior for BlackBerry GUI applications.
     */
    final class PlayMediaScreen extends MainScreen implements PlayerListener
    {
        /**
         * Creates a new PlayMediaScreen object
         */
        Player p = null;
        String mp3 = ""; 
        String test1 = "Test2seconds.mp3";
        String test5 = "Test2seconds2.mp3";
        //String test6 = "Test2seconds3.mp3";
        String test4 = "Test2seconds4.mp3";
        String test2 = "blind_willie.mp3";
        String test3 = "blind_willie2.mp3";


        PlayMediaScreen()
        {
            mp3 = test1;
            play(mp3);
        }

        private void play(String mp3){



        InputStream stream = (InputStream)this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + mp3);

            try {
                //p = Manager.createPlayer(source);
                p = Manager.createPlayer(stream,"audio/mpeg");
                p.addPlayerListener(this);
                p.realize();
                p.prefetch();

                //testing
                System.out.println("Creating Players!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
                System.out.println("The mp3 is " + mp3 + "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

                //testing
                System.out.println("IO Exeception!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!1 " + e);

                //testing 
                System.out.println(p);

            } catch (MediaException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            //testing
            System.out.println("Media Exeception!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!1" + e);

            //testing 
            System.out.println(p);
            }
            /*
             * Best practice is to invoke realize(), then prefetch(), then start().
             * Following this sequence reduces delays in starting media playback.
             *
             * Invoking start() as shown below will cause start() to invoke  prefetch(0),
             * which invokes realize() before media playback is started.
             */
            try {
                p.start();
            } catch (MediaException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

                //testing
                System.out.println("Media Exeception for starting!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!1" + e);

                //testing 
                System.out.println(p);
            }
            /*
            try {
                p.stop();
            } catch (MediaException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            p.deallocate();
            p.close();
            */


        }

        public void playerUpdate(Player player, String event, Object eventData) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (event.equals(PlayerListener.END_OF_MEDIA)) {

                //String mp3 = ""; 

                if( mp3.equals(test1) ) {
                    mp3 = test2;
                    //testing
                    System.out.println("The MP3 is " + mp3 + "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

                    play(mp3);

                    //testing
                    System.out.println("The MP3 FINISH PLAYING is " + mp3 + "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

                }
                 else if( mp3.equals(test2) ){ 
                     mp3 = test3;
                    //testing
                    System.out.println("The MP3 is " + mp3 + "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

                    play(mp3);

                    //testing
                    System.out.println("The MP3 FINISH PLAYING is " + mp3 + "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

                 }
                 else if( mp3.equals(test3) ) {
                     mp3 = test4;
                     //testing
                    System.out.println("The MP3 is " + mp3 + "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

                    play(mp3);

                    //testing
                    System.out.println("The MP3 FINISH PLAYING is " + mp3 + "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

                 }                   
                 else if( mp3.equals(test4) ) {
                     mp3 = test5;
                    //testing
                    System.out.println("The MP3 is " + mp3 + "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

                    play(mp3);

                    //testing
                    System.out.println("The MP3 FINISH PLAYING is " + mp3 + "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

                 }
                 else if( mp3.equals(test5) ){
                     mp3 = null;
                     try {
                        player.stop();
                    } catch (MediaException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                     player.deallocate();
                     player.close();
                 }

              }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I managed to play it, but it did not play the whole sound of the audio files, it just play the first audio files and second for a few seconds, and stop playing after that. The files that played also play the sound overlap each other which should not be happening.

Please reread the [BB API docs](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/javax/microedition/media/Player.html) for `Player` carefully:

> Simple Playback
>
> A Player can be created from one of the Manager's createPlayer methods. After the Player is created, calling start will start the playback as soon as possible. The method will return when the playback is started. The playback will continue in the background and will stop automatically when the end of media is reached.
>
> Simple playback example illustrates this:

```
try {
    Player p = Manager.createPlayer("http://abc.wav");
    p.start();
} catch (MediaException pe) {
} catch (IOException ioe) {
}
```

Note the docs say `The method will return when the playback is started. The playback will continue in the background ..`. This is the reason of you get "sound overlap".

To overcome this you need to attach a listener to the player `Player.addPlayerListener(PlayerListener playerListener)`. The listener will be notified from the background "playback" thread when the media file has been played to the end. And this will be the right moment to start a new playback for the next media file. Please don't expect the code from me, I'm just giving you an idea.

Comment: Hi, can you shown me an example of adding the player listener? Sorry,  I am new to Blackberry, so may need a lit bit more specific example. I can play a simple playback but it just that I can't play multiple audio files one after another. :( Please help!

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an example since I've never used audio playback in my projects. Now that you are instructed what to do and what BB API to use I don't think anything can still keep you from the success.

Comment: Haha, thanks. I try to put in the PlayerListener before, but its giving me the same error. I try to read the document but I don't really understand how it plays an audio file one after another using the playerlistener.